# "You are not a sandbox user of this client" error in Instagram PHP API

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I use the [Instagram PHP API library](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API) to get media from Instagram in PHP.

When I use it with other logged in user in my project, I get this error:

> You are not a sandbox user of this client

My project needs to get posts from an Instagram account without needing to sandbox.

Comment: Possibly due to [Instagram platform update](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API/issues/182)?

Comment: I use update version but not working

Comment: Can you tell what is the sandbox user status is, if possible post a screenshot .

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu User status is SandBox in instagram account

Comment: I am asking it is pending or active ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu it is active(SandBox status)

Comment: for the user with which you are testing ? can you post screenshot ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Screenshot?from source or error?

Comment: screenshot from sandbox where sandbox users are listed .

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu  My sandbox is empty.I need that all user can login with my client id,(dont limit with sandbox)

Comment: if you do not want to limit yourself with sandbox, first approve your app from Instagram team.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Yes i do not want to limit with sandbox,how i approve my app from instagram team?

Comment: read their documentation .

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After complete app or website(that use instagram api) i send it to instagram in panel and if no problem in my project,so instagran verify it and we can use unlimit users for login